# Bad gateway on 2 sites after Certbot changed the Nginx site-conf file of one of them

Tags: nginx, certbot

I experience bad gateway on 2 sites after Certbot changed the Nginx site-conf file of one of them.

No errors all in `nginx -t`.

Only this comes up in `tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`:

> 2017/10/24 15:40:47 [error] 27439#27439: *125 connect() failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   66.249.69.71, server: domain.tld1, request: "GET /category/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "contfix.co.il" root@benqzq:~#

Only this comes up in `tail /var/log/nginx/access.log`:

> 185.188.204.5 - - [24/Oct/2017:15:44:13 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT
>   6.0)"

- No error in nginx reset.

This is the site-conf of the site I changed with Certbot:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/contfix.co.il;
    server_name contfix.co.il www.contfix.co.il;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/contfix.co.il/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/contfix.co.il/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot
}
```

The site-conf file of the second site that I didn't choose to finish with Certbot, stayed the same.

Both sites worked perfectly before installing and working with Certbot.

I went to `nginx/conf.d/ssl` but the files there contain keys and not something to work with to debug this.

How should I further debug this?

### Update

When using Certbot on my domain, I got the error:

```
Could not open file: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

When I did `certbot renew --dry-run` I also got it, but I didn't get it just when doing "certbot renew".

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that the [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) directives regarding my site (responsible for PHP-dependent data processing), as appears in my site-conf file, weren't as they should be after implementing SSL.

This is the new setting that works:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Regarding the error I had with the detault, just go to sites-enabled and delete the symlink inode called default. Thus, even if you have a default template in `sites-available`, it won't be utilized.